# Testing a split API route in django rest framework using pytest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm trying to create a split of routes, creating two APIs. My idea is that my application works in two modes: normal, custom.

Here is an example of my directory structure:

```bash
- config
    - urls.py
- api
    - custom
        - v1
            - urls.py
    - normal
        - v1
            - urls.py
```

For the modes, I'm using environment variables.

In my main urls.py I put it like this:

```py
[...]
router = DefaultRouter()

NORMAL = "normal"
CUSTOM = "custom"


if config.settings.MODE == NORMAL:
    urlpatterns = [
        
        path("normal/v1/", include("api.normal.v1.urls")),
]
elif config.settings == CUSTOM:
    urlpatterns = [
        path("custom/v1/", include("api.custom.v1.urls")),
    ]
```

My urls.py (normal):

```py
[...]
router = DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^", include(router.urls)),
    path("normal-example/", normal.normal-example, name="normal-example/"),
]
```

And my urls.py (custom):

```py
[...]
router = DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^", include(router.urls)),
    path("custom-example/", custom.custom-example, name="custom-example/"),
]
```

Ok. When I run and change, by env, works. Both in normal and custom. My problem is how to test this with pytest.

I tried like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mode_custom(settings):
    settings.MODE = "custom"

def test_custom-example(mode_custom, client):
    resp = client.get("/custom/v1/custom-example/")
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Or using `override_settings` decorator. But the result is the same: It always takes the normal route. It only works in the custom route if I change it in the .env file. Fixtures have no effect.